# SSMS changes password of logins

Tags: sql, authentication, ssms

I am trying to create logins for my server. I type in the login name, password, set appropriate settings.

[image: setting parameters in login creation window]

Then I re-open the properties window by double-clicking the login in `MyDatabase/security/logins` directory.

[image: re-opening properties for the user]

As you may notice, the number of letters in the password is different. Any idea why is it different, or what the "new" password look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password in the Login Properties window is only masked to for security purposes.  For example, if the exact number of characters in the password was displayed this would make it less difficult for someone else attempting to figure out the password is to determine this.  The password of the logins that you created will be the same password that you set when you made the login regardless of what is displayed in that window.